# Viewpager won't work when pressing back from a toolbar

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I tried to phrase the title as I can, but Basically inside the HomeActivity  I have a custom menu with a bunch for fragments.! One of the them is `HomeFragment` which contains a `Tablelayout` of 2 tabs with a `viewpager`..!

Everything is working correctly.! but inside the menu fragment, when the user clicks the back button on the toolbar is to return to the `HomeFragment`.
A fragment replacement method will do the trick which I already used it to replace between the fragments when choosing from the menu !?

But in this case, the `HomeFragment` opens yet the `Tablayout` isn't responsive! it feels like the the fragment isn't created correctly!?

I tried using a new intent of the same activity which opens `HomeFragment` by default, and it opens it but with the same problem..!

---

**The Problem**

[image]

---

**The Code**

HomeFragment

```
// code..

  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
      Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    InitViews(rootView);

    TabLayoutAdapter adapter = new TabLayoutAdapter(getFragmentManager());
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(pager);


    return rootView;
  }

// code..
```

Menu Fragment

```
    // code..

  @Override
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
      case R.id.to_home:

     replaceFragment(new HomeFragment());

       // tried this and it's the same problem 
       // startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(), HomeActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY));
        return true;
      default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
  }

    public void replaceFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction t = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    t.replace(R.id.Container, fragment);
    t.commit();
  }

    // code..
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the code I think you have to use getChildFragmentManager() instead of getFragmentManager() and use it for fragment Transaction.

The definition of getChildFragmentManager() is:
 Return a private FragmentManager for placing and managing Fragments inside of this Fragment.

And the definition of getFragmentManager() is:
Return the FragmentManager for interacting with fragments associated with this fragment's activity.

Replace this line of code having getFragmentManager() by getChildFragmentManager()

```
TabLayoutAdapter adapter = new TabLayoutAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
```

Also in the menu Fragment

```
android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction t = getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

Comment: it gives me `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0d008a (XXX.XXXX:id/Container) for fragment GamesFragment{2b77c84 #2 id=0x7f0d008a}`

Comment: Where is that GamesFragment?

Comment: It's the Menu Fragment..! it's code is posted in the question! why do you think this error shows.!?

Comment: R.id.Container is the framelayout and is present in MenuFragment right?

Comment: yes, I think the problem in HomeActivity , it's the activity that holds all the fragments, i tried to use `replaceFragment()` method there , but `getChildFragmentManager` didn't show !?

Comment: You can use getChildFragmentManager only for fragments as I explained above.It i used for managing Fragments inside of  Fragment.

Comment: you are right, it worked now, i wasn't using the `support.v4` version, once I imported the right one it worked! thanks a lot !

Comment: oh no..seeing your code I thought you were using..Thats why I suggested you to use getSupportManager() instead of getManager(). Anyways I’m glad it helped you :)